# What does "this" actually refer to in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple script (see below) and I expected the `div` to "bounce". However, it doesn't when I use `this.effect("bounce");`. It does work when I use the variable that contains the element: `$arrow_go_up.effect("shake");`

When I `console.log` the `this`, it shows me the element, so I am confused.

I tried to use an arrow-function, then `this` points to the window-element though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $arrow_go_up = $("#arrow_go_up");

  window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 100) {
      $arrow_go_up.removeClass("d-none");
    } else {
      $arrow_go_up.addClass("d-none");
    }
  }

  $arrow_go_up.on("mouseover", function() {
    this.effect("bounce", {
      times: 1
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Inside a jQuery handler, `this` refers to the HTML element. To use jQuery functions, you need to turn it into a jQuery object first: `$(this)`

Comment: `this` in this example is an Element object, whereas `$arrow_go_up` is a jQuery object. The former does not have the `effect()` method available.

Comment: @ChrisG my god... thanks! how did I miss this! thanks a lot!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks alot! makes total sense!

Comment: `console.log(this)`

Comment: @epascarello read the post again (: